Can't connect to internet via ethernet after upgrade to 24.04 (but can connect via wifi)
Upgraded my laptop to 24.04 today. I notice that if I have the laptop connected to ethernet with wifi turned off I can't get out to the internet. I am able to connect other machines on my internal network with the wired ethernet connection. If I turn on wifi I can get out to the internet.
output from ip r

default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto static metric 100
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.2 metric 600


192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.43 metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 600


I found that I could ping 8.8.8.8 with just the ethernet connected. Which led me to suspect a DNS problem. The IP address for the ethernet connection is static. I set the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 in the network settings and it worked fine after that. So maybe some config file got blown away in the upgrade.
